# C# (possibly) using Generics

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to this, so please bear with me.

I have a class which has three properties: a couple of ints and a collection of userdefined objects.

```
public class Response
{
    public int num1 { get; set; }
    public int num2 { get; set; }
    public Drink[] drinks{ get; set; }
}
```

I can instantiate the class using the userdefined objects and everything works great.

```
Response response = new Response
    {
        num1= 7, num2= 2, drinks= new Drink[] 
        { new Drink{Id=1, Name="Orange"}, new Drink{Id=2, Name="Apple"}}
    };
```

How can I make that third property of the Response class to where I can have another instance of the class using a different userdefined object, say, "Snack".

Looking for an online resource to read/learn/figure out more so than an answer, although either would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at .NET generics.

Comment: With a more descriptive title you will get more answers.

Comment: Do want to be able to substitute the `new Drink[]` for `new Snack[]`, while leaving the Response class the way it is?

Comment: Wow, such quick response!  Thanks a lot guys.  Alex, reading up on Generics now.  Jon B. Will modify the title in a minute and keep it in mind going forward.

Comment: Keerigan, yes, exactly. It seems Generics is the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alex suggested, Generics are the solution to the problem as you describe it.  You could redefine your class like this:

```
public class Response<T>
{ 
    public int num1 { get; set; } 
    public int num2 { get; set; } 
    public T[] items{ get; set; } 
}
```

... and then declare your instance like this:

```
Response<Drink> drinkResponse = new Response<Drink>
{              
    num1= 7, num2= 2, items = new Drink[] { new Drink{Id=1, Name="Orange"}, new Drink{Id=2, Name="Apple"}}  
};  

Response<Snack> snackResponse = new Response<Snack>  
{              
    num1= 7, num2= 2, items = new Snack[] { new Snack{Id=1, Name="Orange"}, new Snack{Id=2, Name="Apple"}}  
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great!  I have lots of reading to do regarding Generics.

Answer (score 1):

I **think** you're talking about [inheritance](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson09) here, where you can have multiple classes that share a common structure:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public int num1 { get; set; }
    public int num2 { get; set; }
}

public class DrinkResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public Drink[] drinks { get; set; }
}

public class SnackResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public Snack[] snacks { get; set; }
}
```

[This is an excellent resource](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx) for the basics of C#, once you have that down I further recommend you [also take a look here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327916/C-Language-Features-From-C-2-0-to-4-0) for advanced C# 4.0 specific stuff.

**Edit**

To support the other guys, they make a very good point I didn't think of at first **Generics** - [here is a great article about their usage](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson20).

Answer (score 1):

Just Like Alex Farber said, you could create a Generic class.

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public int num1 { get; set; }
    public int num2 { get; set; }
    public T[] items{ get; set; }
}
```

More information on generic classes : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public int num1 { get; set; }
    public int num2 { get; set; }
    public T[] food { get; set; }
}

Response<Drink> response = new Response<Drink>
    {
        num1= 7, num2= 2, food = new Drink[] 
        { new Drink{Id=1, Name="Orange"}, new Drink{Id=2, Name="Apple"}}
    };

Response<Snack> response = new Response<Snack>
    {
        num1= 7, num2= 2, food = new Snack[] 
        { new Snack{Id=1, Name="Orange"}, new Snack{Id=2, Name="Apple"}}
    };
```